# Retrieve the virtual page id from a virtual address

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, memory, system-calls

We know this following function from Linux kernel, which takes a pointer to the struct page and outputs the virtual address of the page frame:

```
void * page_address(struct page *page)
```

So I wonder if a function in a reserved version is available: taking a virtual memory address and outputting the corresponding virtual page id?
(The output should not be a `struct page` in-memory data structure because of the assumption, that a page could be swapped to the disk.)

Thanks. Correct me, if I am wrong or have a duplicated question over SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading several virtual address translation post, I found the **virtual page number** is an intermediate result in the translation and is mentioned in those posts.

Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45128487/10971650.

What's relevant here is the variable `vpn` for the virtual page number. (I use the function [getpagesize](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpagesize.2.html) instead.)

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uintptr_t get_virtual_page_number (uintptr_t vaddr) {
  return vaddr / getpagesize();
}
```